# Refresh parent's KoGrid from child form

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

On the main page I have a grid

```
    <div data-bind="setGridCell: 12,
        component: {
            name: 'ko.widget.koGrid',
            params: {
                id: 'gridId',
                lazyLoad: true,
                autoPopulate: false,
                url : someurl;
            }">
   </div>
```

And a child component

```
    <div data-bind="setGridCell: 12,
        component: {
            name: 'ko.view.report.confirmationWindow',
            params: params()
        }">
   </div>
```

The child component will open a small window that allows me to change the data inside the grid component (both are linked to web services).

Right now, when I click the "Submit" button on the child component, the data change is sent to the service and update in the database, the child component is also closed.

However, display-wise, the grid still looks exactly the same. I'm new to knockout.js in general so I'm not sure what's the best way to go about refreshing (in-place) the data in the grid so that the user can immediately see the changes.

Thanks in advance!

(everything is inside a .NET C# application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the observable model to the component and use the params in your components bindings.  The only thing to watch out for is when you are inserting a new row to a database and do not have the ID.  You have to set the ID when your save is complete leaving the component open until you get a return from your message.